# Help reading this mathematical notation?

Tags: notation

$$E(D_j|v_j) = \sum_{i=1}^n a^{v_j(i)}_i * b^{1-v_j(i)}_i = v^T_j \overset{\rightarrow}{a}+(¬v_j)^T\overset{\rightarrow}{b}$$

Please excuse the ignorance of my math, but I am having trouble interpreting the following notation. Specifically, does the $|$ in $(D_j|v_j)$ refer to "divided by", or "given", or "or"? And why are there two equal signs, what's the purpose of the last sequence $= v^T_j \overset{\rightarrow}{a}+(¬v_j)^T\overset{\rightarrow}{b}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertical bar probably means "given" since the $E$ is probably an expectation.

There are two equal signs because the author is telling you that $E$ is given by the first expression which s/he claims works out to be the second - hence the second equal sign.

You can only get the purpose of the last sequence from context. Presumably it's a useful way to work with the expectation $E$.